# Continuing training (image_retraining/retrain.py) by loading an intermediate_output_graphs(.pb)

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I'm using the retrain script provided in the image_retraining folder from the tensorflow repository.

One of the parser arguments/flags let you store intermediate graphs every X steps

```
parser.add_argument(
      '--intermediate_output_graphs_dir',
      type=str,
      default='tf_files2/tmp/intermediate_graph/',
      help='Where to save the intermediate graphs.'
```

However, this seems to store the graph as a frozen graph with .pb extension.
There is very little information on how to properly load a .pb file to continue training.
Most of the info I found uses .meta graphs and .ckpts.
Is .pb going to be deprecated?

If so, should I just retrain the model from start and use a tf.Saver to get
.meta and ckpt graphs as intermediate checkpoints?

Yesterday, I was training a model and for some reason training froze, so I want to load up the intermediate graph, and continue training.

I'm using the inception model for retraining:
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/retrain.py

If anyone could point me or show me how to properly load up a .pb intermediate graph (step by step) and continue from where I left off -- I would really appreciate it.

Thank you.

EDIT:

@Mingxing

So I'm assuming I should just let retrain.py first create the default graph based on default inception model (This function below) and then just overwrite it with the loaded graph?

```
def create_model_graph(model_info):
  """"Creates a graph from saved GraphDef file and returns a Graph object.

  Args:
    model_info: Dictionary containing information about the model architecture.

  Returns:
    Graph holding the trained Inception network, and various tensors we'll be
    manipulating.
  """
  with tf.Graph().as_default() as graph:
    model_path = os.path.join(FLAGS.model_dir, model_info['model_file_name'])
    with gfile.FastGFile(model_path, 'rb') as f:
      graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
      graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())
      bottleneck_tensor, resized_input_tensor = (tf.import_graph_def(
          graph_def,
          name='',
          return_elements=[
              model_info['bottleneck_tensor_name'],
              model_info['resized_input_tensor_name'],
          ]))
  return graph, bottleneck_tensor, resized_input_tensor
```

EDIT_2:

An error I'm getting is:

```
ValueError: Tensor("second_to_final_fC_layer_ops/weights/final_weights_1:0", shape=(2048, 102
4), dtype=float32_ref) must be from the same graph as Tensor("BottleneckInputPlaceholder:0",
shape=(?, 2048), dtype=float32).
```

I had added an extra FC layer after the first FC layer.
So 2048 -> 1024 -> num of classes prior to tranining.

When training the model I had no problems, but now loading the graph I seem to be running into this error above.

This is how the added layer looks:

```
layer_name = 'second_to_final_fC_layer_ops'
  with tf.name_scope(layer_name):
    with tf.name_scope('weights'):
      initial_value = tf.truncated_normal(
          [bottleneck_tensor_size, 1024], stddev=0.001)

      layer_weights = tf.Variable(initial_value, name='weights')

      variable_summaries(layer_weights)
   with tf.name_scope('biases'):
      layer_biases = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([1024]), name='biases')
      variable_summaries(layer_biases)
   with tf.name_scope('Wx_plus_b'):
      logits = tf.matmul(bottleneck_input, layer_weights) + layer_biases
      tf.summary.histogram('pre_activations', logits)
    with tf.name_scope('Relu_activation'):
      relu_activated =tf.nn.relu(logits, name= 'Relu')
      tf.summary.histogram('final_relu_activation', relu_activated)
```

And then the final layer (which was the original final layer, but now the inputs are the outputs from last layer instead of the bottleneck tensor):

```
layer_name = 'final_training_ops'
  with tf.name_scope(layer_name):
    with tf.name_scope('weights'):
      initial_value = tf.truncated_normal(
          [1024, class_count], stddev=0.001)

      layer_weights = tf.Variable(initial_value, name='final_weights')

      variable_summaries(layer_weights)
    with tf.name_scope('biases'):
      layer_biases = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([class_count]), name='final_biases')
      variable_summaries(layer_biases)
    with tf.name_scope('Wx_plus_b'):
      logits = tf.matmul(relu_activated, layer_weights) + layer_biases
      tf.summary.histogram('pre_activations', logits)

  final_tensor = tf.nn.softmax(logits, name=final_tensor_name)
  tf.summary.histogram('activations', final_tensor)
```

EDIT: Still don't know how to load the weights-- Loading the graph structure seems to be easy, but I don't know how to load the weights and inputs of Inception that has been used trained once again using transfer learning.

A clear example using the weights and variables from image_retraining/retrain.py would be really helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [tf.import_graph_def](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/import_graph_def) to import your frozen .pb file:

```
# Read the .pb file into graph_def.
with tf.gfile.GFile(FLAGS.graph, "rb") as f:
    graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
    graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())

# Restore the graph. 
with tf.Graph().as_default() as graph:
    tf.import_graph_def(graph_def, name="")

# After this, graph is the what you need.
```

Although there is nothing wrong to directly use frozen .pb file, I still want to point out that the recommended way is to follow the standard save/restore ([official doc](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/saved_model)).

Comment: Thank you. I updated my OP with another question regarding the solution. When you have time, please take a look. Thank you =)

Comment: I created another update regarding an error I'm getting. No rush. Just logging in the update. Thank you.